# Any more efficient way for custom preg_replace function?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, security, performance

I plan to use my custom function below while getting from data from my mysql table & print it as html. Since htmlspecialchars() translate tags to html entities, I retranslate them ( p, br, strong) to tags. 
My question is: Is it efficient enough or Is there any other shorter or more efficient way to achieve this aim? If you know any, can you please guide me with at least keywords? I can look fort he details in php.net and this site. 
Thanks, regards

```
    function safe_output_from_mysql($safe_echo_to_html)
{
    $safe_echo_to_html = mb_convert_encoding($safe_echo_to_html, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($safe_echo_to_html));
    $safe_safe_echo_to_html = htmlspecialchars($safe_echo_to_html, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $safe_echo_to_html = preg_replace("&lt;br /&gt;","<br />",$safe_echo_to_html);
    $safe_echo_to_html = preg_replace("&lt;p&gt;","<p>",$safe_echo_to_html);
    $safe_echo_to_html = preg_replace("&lt;/p&gt;","</p>",$safe_echo_to_html);
    $safe_echo_to_html = preg_replace("&lt;strong&gt;","<strong>",$safe_echo_to_html);
    $safe_echo_to_html = preg_replace("&lt;/strong&gt;","</strong>",$safe_echo_to_html);
    return $safe_echo_to_html;
}
```

Comment: Since you are not using regular expressions, you should just be using `str_replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call preg_replace() multiple times. You can use a single pattern to match all the desired tags:

```
preg_replace('/&lt;\s*(\/?(?:strong|p|br)\s*\/?)&gt;/i', '<\1>', $s);
```

I'm assuming, of course, that you're actually planning to use regex to do the match. If the search strings are straight text, then strtr() is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

htmlspecialchars_decode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

This function is the opposite of htmlspecialchars(). It converts special HTML entities back to characters.

```
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

The above example will output:

```
<p>this -> "</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I intentionally didn’t use htmlspecialchars_decode function; because: think the case that a bad user inputs this piece of code into my comment textarea <?php echo ”I warn you. Be careful with your code. This is printed with php code.”; ?> If I decode everything from my mysql then this means that I am opened to XSS attacks, right? So I don’t think that I should use htmlspecialchars_decode function. I learned from php.net that escape what you need and decode what you need only again. Please correct me ıf I am wrong. regards

Answer (score 2):

Please see the function htmlspecialchars_decode($str); function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I intentionally didn’t use htmlspecialchars_decode function; because: think the case that a bad user inputs this piece of code into my comment textarea <?php echo ”I warn you. Be careful with your code. This is printed with php code.”; ?> If I decode everything from my mysql then this means that I am opened to XSS attacks, right? So I don’t think that I should use htmlspecialchars_decode function. I learned from php.net that escape what you need and decode what you need only again. Please correct me ıf I am wrong. regards